# mocha error : invalide usage of console logs detected

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, loopback

All my test passed successfully.
But at the end I have this message :

```
  32 passing (7s)
=== ATTENTION - INVALID USAGE OF CONSOLE LOGS DETECTED ===
[------------all logs here------------]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 10
npm ERR! MyProject@1.0.0 test: 'lb-mocha --opts tests/mocha.opts'
npm ERR! Exit status 10
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the MyProject@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-03T09_57_58_382Z-debug.log
```

Here are my mocha.opts :

```
--allow-console-logs
--recursive
--require ts-node/register
tests/**/*.ts
--exit
```

Do you know why it's not working ?

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake.

`--allow-console-logs` is NOT a mocha cli options. This is a "lb-mocha" cli option, meaning that is only dependent to loopback. That's why it was not interpreted by mocha in the `mocha.opts` file. The solution is to extract this argument from mocha option file to the test commande line in the `package.json`, see below:

```
//package.json//
{
  ...
  "script": {
    ...
    "test": "lb-mocha --allow-console-logs --opts tests/mocha.opts"
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Don't forget to remove the argument from `mocha.opts` file:

```
//mocha.opts//
--recursive
--require ts-node/register
tests/**/*.ts
--exit
```

I hope it will save your day.